# nohup output redirection to a different file

Tags: bash, nohup

I use [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) quite often for important long running processes under `linux`/`bash`, so much so that `nohup time my command with arguments && mv nohup.out my.log` is almost an idiom for me.

The problem is that `nohup` puts both `stdout` and `stderr` into `nohup.out`, and I cannot control the name of the file. This means that if I accidentally start two `nohup`s in the same directory, their output will be interleaved in `nohup.out`.

The questions are:

1. How do I deal with this problem? Always running `nohup`s in separate directories and writing a shell function which will first check for `./nohup.out` are two sucky options I see.
2. How come I cannot tell `nohup` where to redirect the output? GNU tools tend to have [so many options](http://www.netfunny.com/rhf/jokes/88q3/2104.6.html), why not `nohup`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [redirect both stdout and stderr](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) to one file. With Bash 4 (or others such as Zsh), as easy as:

```
nohup <some-command> &> output.log
```

I can't tell you why there's no separate option for `nohup` to set the output, but if your shell can take care of that, you don't really need an option.

Comment: Will it prevent `nohup` from performing its own redirection?

Comment: GNU `nohup` says that it'll redirect stdout to a file if you specify `nohup command > file`. BSD `nohup` doesn't mention this at all, but it worked for me.

Comment: *GNU nohup says that it'll redirect stdout to a file if you specify `nohup command > file`* Isn't redirection in case of `nohup command > file` being handled by shell and not `nohup`? If so then how can `nohup` take any action based on weather redirection is present or not?

Comment: The file `nohup.out` will be created in the case of error output, too; but if you redirect both stdout and stderr, there cannot be any output, so the file will not be created.  But the `&>` syntax is not POSIX-compliant; you're better off with the answer by Irshad Khan elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 8):

To **Append output in user defined file** you can use `>>` in nohup command.

```
nohup php your_command >> filename.out 2>&1 &
```

This command will append all output in your file without removing old data.

Comment: And if you want to overwrite the output file using POSIX `sh` syntax, that's simply `nohup your_command >filename.out 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 3):

There are more ways than just `nohup` to start a process so that it would ignore SIGHUP; for example: (written as shell functions)

```
nohup() {
    setsid "$@"
}

nohup() {
    ("$@" &)
}

nohup() {
    "$@" & disown
}
```

(`setsid`, or even `(setsid "$@" &)`, might be the best choice.)

All of them allow you to specify your own redirections with `>`, `2>`, and `&>`/`>&`.